Is this "continuous" function really continuous?
Let's assume $n \ge 2.$ Suppose $f:\Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^{n+1}$ has the form
$$
f(x,t) = (\phi_t(x),t),
$$
where $\phi_{t_0}:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ is a continuous function for each fixed $t_0$. Assuming also that there exists a dense set $D\subset \Bbb R^n$ such that for each $x_0 \in D$, the map $f(x_0,\cdot)$, which is the restriction of $f$ to the line $\{x_0\}\times \Bbb R$, is uniformly continuous.

Is it true that $f$ must be continuous?

I suspect that the answer is negative, but I cannot think of a counterexample yet. Of course, here we are talking about the standard Euclidean topology only.

No, this is not necessarily true. As an example, let $n = 2$, $\phi_t: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be defined by,
$$\phi_t(x, y) = \begin{cases}
(t^{|x|}, y) &, \text{ if }t \in (0, 1], x \in [-1, 1]\\
(t, y) &, \text{ if }t \in (0, 1], x \notin [-1, 1]\\
(0, y) &, \text{ if }t \leq 0\\
(1, y) &, \text{ if }t > 1
\end{cases}$$
Then indeed $\phi_t$ is a continuous (in fact, uniformly continuous) function for each $t$. Let $D = (\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}) \times \mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, which is dense. For any $x_0 \in D$, one easily verifies that $f(x_0, \cdot)$ is uniformly continuous. But $f$ is not continuous. In fact, $f((0, 0), \cdot)$ is not continuous. It has a jump discontinuity at $t = 0$.

Here is an even simpler example with the even stronger condition that $D = \mathbb{R}^2$:
$$\phi_t(x, y) = \begin{cases}
(\frac{\min\{t^2, x^2\}}{t^2 + x^2}, y) &, \text{ if }(t, x) \neq (0, 0)\\
(0, y) &, \text{ if }(t, x) = (0, 0)
\end{cases}$$
Then $\phi_t$ is uniformly continuous for any $t$ and $f(x_0, \cdot)$ is uniformly continuous for any $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^2$. But $f$ is not continuous, since,
$$\lim_{x \to 0} f((x, x), x) = (\frac{1}{2}, 0, 0) \neq (0, 0, 0) = f((0, 0), 0)$$

I should note that these are quite standard examples. I simply adapted them to the OP’s specific question.

Thank you for the nice examples. I forgot to write in the question that I want $\phi_t$ to be injective on $D$ as well, but that is too late to edit it now since you have already perfectly answered the original question. Do you happen to know a good counterexample if we add this further condition?

@BigbearZzz By $\phi_t$ being injective on $D$, do you mean the map $t \mapsto \phi_t(x_0)$ is injective for all $x_0 \in D$? In that case just change the second example to $\frac{t^3}{|t|^3 + |x|^3}$. Then $D = (\mathbb{R} \setminus {0}) \times \mathbb{R}$ works.

Sorry I wasn't being clear. I meant that for each fixed $t$, the map $x\mapsto \phi_t(x)$ is injective on $D$ (but could potentially be non-injective on $\Bbb R^n$).

@BigbearZzz In that case, let $\phi_t(x, y) = (\frac{x^2}{t^2 + x^2} + x^2, y)$ if $(t, x) \neq (0, 0)$ and $\phi_0(0, y) = (1, y)$. Let $A$ be the set of positive algebraic numbers and negative transcendental numbers. Then $D = A \times \mathbb{R}$ works.

That sounds good, thanks again! By the way, the only reason I set $n \ge 2$ is because I thought the statement may be true for $n=1$ so I wanted to avoid that. However, since all the examples you gave work for $n=1$ as well, it seems that the assumption $n \ge 2$ is superfluous after all.

@BigbearZzz Yeah. I was actually thinking with $n = 1$. I just added an extra variable $y$ to satisfy the $n \geq 2$ condition.

I could see that too :)
